# Is it possible to store Audit4j audit events into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, audit4j

We want to save audit4j events/logs (which are usually stored in text file) to mongodb.

Is it possible with some existing adapter/plugin? Or need to write on?  If we need to write any documentation which can be referred to?

Most of the article talks about auditing mongodb changes itself, hence we are confused.

Any pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Please share the solution if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin available on github https://github.com/nipunthathsara/Audit4j-MongoDB